# Reading CIFAR10 data with java

Tags: java, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-recognition

I am working on a Machine Learning project with the [CIFAR10](http://www.kaggle.com/c/cifar-10/data) dataset and I am looking for the fastest way to process the data using Java. It consists of 60,000 32x32 color images. The images are in png format.

I want to store the image as raw pixels (32x32x3) in order to extract features from each image.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What aspects of the images are you looking at? Raw pixels? Or do you only need a subset of each image?

Comment: Raw pixels. I need to be able to extract the features for each image. Then I'll use convolutional neural networks to classify the images (there are 10 classes in the data set).

Comment: What approaches have you currently tried, and what issues (performance, reliability) do you need help addressing?

Comment: I have been working with BufferedImage to read in each image and convert it to a 32x32x3 matrix. Given the size of my data, this takes a significant amount of time. I am trying to find a way to save the data in a different format that would be quick to read.